# Is there an idiom that means "something is underappreciated or undervalued"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "something is underappreciated or undervalued"? I am trying to find a nice way to say that something is undervalued or underappreciated, but I can't think of any expression, phrases to mean exactly that.

Comment: Why are *underappreciated* and *undervalued* insufficient? Do you consider them not to be nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Underrated" is another way of saying "underappreciated" or "undervalued"; it's a bit more colloquial than either of those words, and probably a bit more common, as well.

However, it isn't really nicer, *per se,* and I don't think most English speakers would consider it rude, disparaging or "not nice" to describe something as "undervalued" or "underappreciated."

Answer (score 0):

You don’t miss the water until the well runs dry.

> [you never miss the water till the well runs dry](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/you+never+miss+the+water+till+the+well+runs+dry)
> It is only when someone or something is gone that we truly appreciate them or it.
>
> *I was in such a rush to start a career and become an adult, but now all I want is the carefree life I had when I was in college! You never miss the water till the well runs dry, huh?*
> *I should have made a greater effort to show Janet just how much she meant to me, but you never miss the water till the well runs dry. Now she's married and living on the other side of the planet.*
>
> (TFD)

Comment: We ask that answers include an explanation or reference to reputable sources. I've included one for you.